# Automapper very simple nested mapping doesn't work

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to understand why this configuration doesn't map the `Company` property. Should it work as described [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Nested-mappings.html)?

```cs
public class CreateAccountViewModel 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string VatNumber { get; set; }
    public string Acronym { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string VatNumber { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }

}

public class Company
{
    public string Acronym { get; set; }
}

public class UnitTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void Foo() 
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<CreateAccountViewModel, Account>();
            cfg.CreateMap<CreateAccountViewModel, Company>();
        });

        config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}
```

test result:

```
  Message: 
    AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException : 
    Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
    Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
    For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
    =====================================================================
    CreateAccountViewModel -> Account (Destination member list)
    Kairos.UnitTests.CreateAccountViewModel -> Kairos.UnitTests.Account (Destination member list)

    Unmapped properties:
    Company
```

Comment: in documentation destination and source exactly matches but in your sample you are using `string Acronym` instead of `Company Company`. Here is the problem I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoMapper is unable to deduce that `Acronym` should be mapped from a property on the object referenced by the `Company` property. By renaming the target property to `CompanyAcronym`, AutoMapper should be able to link the two together, as described [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html).

Comment: Or, without rename, http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers.

Answer (score 1):

Your case and example are not the same case. In your case you need add custom mapping for mapping Acronym property to Company instance.

`AutoMapper` from your example knows how to map `CreateAccountViewModel` to `Account` and `CreateAccountViewModel` to `Company` but doesn't know how to map string property `Acronym` to `Company`.